# How to add a new column by searching for data in a Pandas time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

I have a Pandas time series dataframe.
It has minute data for a stock for 30 days.
I want to create a new column, stating the price of the stock at 6 AM for that day, e.g. for all lines for January 1, I want a new column with the price at noon on January 1, and for all lines for January 2, I want a new column with the price at noon on January 2, etc.

```
Existing timeframe:
Date   Time   Last_Price   Date   Time   12amT
1/1/19 08:00  100          1/1/19 08:00  ?
1/1/19 08:01  101          1/1/19 08:01  ?
1/1/19 08:02  100.50       1/1/19 08:02  ?
...
31/1/19 21:00 106         31/1/19 21:00  ?
```

I used this hack, but it is very slow, and I assume there is a quicker and easier way to do this.

```py
for lab, row in df.iterrows() :
    t=row["Date"]
    df.loc[lab,"12amT"]=df[(df['Date']==t)&(df['Time']=="12:00")]["Last_Price"].values[0]
```

Comment: Please show desired result

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use groupby with pd.Grouper:

For pandas 24.1+

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))[0]\
  .transform(lambda x: x.loc[(x.index.hour == 12) & 
                             (x.index.minute==0)].to_numpy()[0])
```

Older pandas use:

```
 df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))[0]\
   .transform(lambda x: x.loc[(x.index.hour == 12) &
                              (x.index.minute==0)].values[0])
```

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(48*60), index=pd.date_range('02-01-2019',periods=(48*60), freq='T'))

df['12amT'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))[0].transform(lambda x: x.loc[(x.index.hour == 12)&(x.index.minute==0)].to_numpy()[0])
```

Output (head):

```
                    0  12amT
2019-02-01 00:00:00  0    720
2019-02-01 00:01:00  1    720
2019-02-01 00:02:00  2    720
2019-02-01 00:03:00  3    720
2019-02-01 00:04:00  4    720
```

Comment: Great answer Scott! Is there a rule of thumb for when to use `Grouper` over `groupby`? Also, does `transform` automatically stretch a scalar value to fit the index of the original df?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I am using groupby with a pd.Grouper object to group by index daily.  pd.Grouper(freq='D') is a helper object I use to time span groupings.  And yes, transform return the same length of the input column.  So, I am getting a scalar value out and transform is making it "stretch" to the input column length.  Let's say you just wanted the first value of each day, then you could do, ...transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]) and that will return the first value in that group for each record.

Comment: Thanks Scott.

How do you also get the next days 12am price too please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have two DateTime columns, I made my own example to demonstrate:

```
ind = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', '30/1/2019', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Last_Price':np.random.random(len(ind)) + 100}, index=ind)

def noon_price(df):
    noon_price = df.loc[df.index.hour == 12, 'Last_Price'].values
    noon_price = noon_price[0] if len(noon_price) > 0 else np.nan
    df['noon_price'] = noon_price
    return df

df.groupby(df.index.day).apply(noon_price).reindex(ind)
```

`reindex` by default will fill each day's rows with its `noon_price`.

To add a column with the *next day*'s noon price, you can `shift` the column 24 rows down, like this:

```
df['T+1'] = df.noon_price.shift(-24)
```

Comment: No problem with asking, that's what SO is for! Two things - 1) Maybe copy this code into your question at the top 2) Did you try Scott Boston's solution?

Comment: Hi,
I tried Scott's solution too but it is a lot slower.
Any idea how I could use your code above to get next working days noon price too please?
Should I create a new T+1 column & then use that instead of df.index.day?  Would this work?
Sorry, I am a complete beginner as you can probably tell!

Comment: Hi Dan, both my and Scott's solutions will produce the "noon price" for each day contained in the dataframe - try it and see! If there are still issues, please clarify.

Comment: Hi, yes. It works perfectly, thanks. It is the noon price of the same day. However I am also trying to add a T+1 noon price column too which is the noon price of the next working day. I cannot seem to do this.

Comment: OK, I've added a line at the bottom - try it and see if it works! Note that this will have blanks (NaN) for the last day of the month, since the information for that day is in the future.

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks so much. Will try when I get home. I had to amend day to date as I have more 1 month of data.